# Auth0 does not work with Gatsby slugs generated from DatoCMS models

Tags: gatsby, auth0

My app successfully gets slug names from each profile in DatoCMS and creates a slug so that a profile can be reached at .com/profiles/[someprofilename].

I am now trying to integrate Auth0. The started Auth0 project [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/gatsby-auth0) puts the Auth0 related "pages" into the Pages folder, while Auth.js is in a Utils folder.

Note: I do have my keys and such in the .env file and Dotenv seems to be functioning property.

This setup gives me the following error:
[image]

I don't understand the underpinnings and would really be thankful for other sets of eyes on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the gatsby docs on environment variables and dotenv ([enter link description here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/))I found my issue.

Gatsby.config was importning Dotenv but I needed to pass in a path like so:

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});
```

I then had to rename my .env to .env.development, which I guess was what Gatsby would be looking for when running npm run develop.